# $ \langle X\rangle=\operatorname{Im} \bar{\tau} $

Tags: ring-theory

Let $A$ be a semigroup, and let $X \subseteq A$ be a subset of $A$, let $\tau: X \rightarrow A$ be the inclusion map and let $\bar{\tau}: W(X) \rightarrow A$ be the evaluation map given by $x \mapsto \tau(x)$ for all $x \in X .)$

Prove that
$$
\langle X\rangle=\operatorname{Im} \bar{\tau}
$$
I've been asked to do this exercise but I don't where to start, could anybody help me?

Comment: Sorry, I find this unclear: What are the domain and codomain of $\tilde{\tau}$, or rather, how is it supposed to be different from $\tau$?

Comment: Is "evaluation map" in this context a technical term with a definition somewhere in your source? If so, please provide that definition. Are you sure $\bar\tau$ is not supposed to be $X^+ \to A$ (where $X^+$ is the free semigroup over $X$) rather than $A\to A$?

Comment: The definition for the evaluation map is given in a previous exercise, maybe I have misinterpreted it. It is the following:Let $\psi: X \rightarrow A$ be an arbitrary map. Denote by $\tau: X \rightarrow W(X)$ the inclusion map: $\tau(x)=x$ for all $x \in X$. Prove that there exists a unique homomorphism of semigroups $\bar{\psi}: W(X) \rightarrow A$ such that $\bar{\psi} \circ \tau=\psi$. The homomorphism $\bar{\psi}$ is called the evaluation map given by $x \mapsto \psi(x)$ for all $x \in X $

Comment: @Max: That definition makes sense in itself; apparently your book uses the notation $W(X)$ for what I called $X^+$. But then your $\bar\tau$ should definitely be $W(X)\to X$, not $A\to A$. Note that $\psi:X\to A$ became $\bar\psi:W(X)\to A$, so the overline should work by wrapping the domain in a $W$.

Comment: @Troposphere Okay, thanks!

Comment: With this correction you should at least be able to do one of the inclusions between $\langle X\rangle$ and $\operatorname{\mathrm{Im}} \bar\tau$ yourself ...